# MySQL / SQL Server... working together as a total solution

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to user sql server for analysis services, and a few other small apps.

The majority of our systems are in MySQL. Things like user info, customer info, sales data I need to get into SQL Server.

Obviously, there is much to debate here. What I was attempting to do is to dump a read only copy into SQL Server so I can user reporting services / analysis services.

Now before you go ahead and say that you can just access MySQL in report services, small things don't work, like stored proc column names in the report designer etc..

Is anyone doing this? Do shops out there run both happily and have some sort of sync go on?

Comment: is there a reason you don't simply migrate to SQL Server?

Comment: Agreed, why not just go with SQL Server? It's far more full featured, and you can get it free (SQL Express).

Comment: I thought about that, things like WordPress, silverstripe etc seem to play nicer with MySQL.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your code is mysql, then you may as well leave it like that. You can easily use SSIS to pull data in from mysql, and make it data warehouse friendly.

I have plenty of clients who pull data in from a variety of systems. It's not worth trying to make them all use SQL Server, no matter how much my SQL expertise would like that.

Comment: I think your right, does SQL Server Standard Edition SSIS do a scheduled pump or something?

Comment: SSIS can be scheduled easily using SQL Server Agent (or any other scheduling tool for that matter). SSIS just sucks. I mean, SSIS just does the sucking of data out of your various systems.